# Can Mathematica find an expression for the distribution of the median of N i.i.d. random variables?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I posted this question on Math, but there has been silence there since. So, I wonder if anyone here can get any closer to the answer to my question using Mathematica. Here is the question:

Suppose I draw $N$ random variables from independent but identical uniform distributions, where $N$ is an even integer. I now sort the drawn values and find the two middlemost of these. Finally, I calculate a simple average of these two middlemost values.

Is there a closed-form description of the progression of distributions that arise as $N$ increases from $N=2$ to $N=∞$ ? The first distribution is easily found to be Triangular, but what about the rest? Plots from simulations in MATLAB, with a uniform distribution on the range 0 to 1, provide the following illustrations:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Mathematica* does make this pretty easy.  The statistic of interest is the typical estimator of the median when the sample size is even.  When the sample size is odd the sample median has a beta distribution:

```
OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n}, (n + 1)/2]
(* BetaDistribution[(1 + n)/2, 1 + 1/2 (-1 - n) + n] *)
```

Now for the case when $n$ is even.  First find the joint distribution of the middle two order statistics.  Then find the distribution of the mean of those two statistics.

```
n = 6;
od = OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n}, {n/2, n/2 + 1}];

md = TransformedDistribution[(x1 + x2)/2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] od];

PDF[md, x]
```

[image: PDF of distribution]

```
Plot[Evaluate[PDF[md, x]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Density function]

To obtain the distribution for general $n$ when $n$ is even we have to use some other than `TransformedDistribution`.  We need to integrate the joint density function and treat $0<x<1/2$, $x=1/2$, and $1/2<x<1$ separately.

```
fltOneHalf = 2 Integrate[(x1^(-1 + n/2) (1 - x2)^(-1 + n/2) n!)/((-1 + n/2)!)^2 /. 
  x2 -> 2 x - x1, {x1, 0, x}, Assumptions -> n > 1 && 0 < x < 1/2]
(* -((4 ((1 - 2 x) x)^(n/2) Gamma[n]*
  Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n/2, n/2, (2 + n)/2, x/(-1 + 2 x)])/((-1 + 2 x)*
  Gamma[n/2]^2)) *) 

fOneHalf = 2 Integrate[(x1^(-1 + n/2) (1 - x2)^(-1 + n/2) n!)/((-1 + n/2)!)^2 /.
  x2 -> 1 - x1, {x1, 0, 1/2}, Assumptions -> n > 1]
(* (2^(2 - n) n!)/((-1 + n) ((-1 + n/2)!)^2) *)

(* Because the density is symmetric, we'll take advantage of that *)
fgtOneHalf = FullSimplify[fltOneHalf /. x -> y /. y -> 1 - x]
(* (4 (-1 + (3 - 2 x) x)^(n/2) Gamma[n]*
  Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n/2, n/2, (2 + n)/2, (-1 + x)/(-1 + 2 x)])/((-1 + 2 x) Gamma[n/2]^2) *)
```

Putting this together in a single function:

```
pdf[n_, x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{-((4 ((1 - 2 x) x)^(n/2)*Gamma[n] Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n/2, n/2, (2 + n)/2, 
       x/(-1 + 2 x)])/((-1 + 2 x) Gamma[n/2]^2)), 0 < x < 1/2},
   {(2^(2 - n) n!)/((-1 + n) ((-1 + n/2)!)^2), x == 1/2},
   {(4 (-1 + (3 - 2 x) x)^(n/2) * Gamma[n]*
 Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n/2, n/2, (2 + n)/2, (-1 + x)/(-1 + 2 x)])/((-1 + 2 x) Gamma[n/2]^2), 
    1/2 < x < 1}}, 0]
```

Comment: Wow that is pretty slick. One interesting thing is that Mathematica only seems to like to compute the ones with even `n`, perhaps because `OrderDistribution` doesn't like fractional values or perhaps because those are the only ones where the polynomials work out.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm in the process of adding in the code for odd `n` and the formulas for general `n`.  Should be able to get to that in about an hour.

Comment: I'm interested in what the general form looks like... I took a bit of time to try to find a pattern for these even `n` but still no dice.

Comment: If you plot this for `n = 1...50` you get quite the distribution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t4HQ.png Looks as if the thing will never level out, which suggests that in the limit of `n->Infinity` this'd go to a delta distribution centered at `x=1/2`

Comment: That would make quite some T-shirt!

Comment: For general `n`, you can still get the result with `TransformedDistribution`: `PDF[TransformedDistribution[(x1 + x2)/2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 2 n}, {n, n + 1}]], x]`. Then just replace `n -> n/2`. You'll have to wait a bit for the result, though.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks.  That took 2 minutes on my laptop.  (I certainly wasn't patient enough when trying that before.  How things have changed since the punch card days!)  However, it doesn't deal with `x = 1/2` as it gives an `Indeterminate` in that case.  But I'll add that into the answer.  Thanks, again!

Comment: Oh well, a single point on the `x` axis doesn't matter in a continuous PDF anyway (as long as there's no delta spike there) :P. You can always ask for the `CDF` instead, which does cover the point `x = 1/2`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Just saw one more issue with the use of `TransformedDistribution` for the general case. For 1/2<x<1 there is the term $B_{2-\frac{1}{x}}(-2 n,n+1)$. One obtains ComplexInfinity for this term and therefore ComplexInfinity when 1/2<x<1. So only the density between 0 and 1/2 gets the correct density. I'll have to look into that more closely.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit For whatever it's worth, I've submitted a question to Wolfram Support about the symbolic approach resulting in the wrong answer for $1/2 < x < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting counter-example for a ***discrete uniform*** distribution does not tend to your shape as $N$ grows.

Let your r.v. $x$ be distributed as per a coin toss, taking value ${0,1}$ with equal probability. Then you have three possible outcomes after $N$ coin tosses; $0, 1/2$ , or $1$

The middle outcome's probability is the probability that with $N$ coin tosses you get exactly $N/2$ zeros or ones. This probability is

$$
2^{-n} \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}
$$

Which decreases in $N$, resulting in the plot below, with the distribution of probabilities of values with $N$

[image]

**EDIT**

You can see the same effect with the discrete distribution for $x$ expanded to take values $x=\{1, 2, ... , 50\}$ with equal probability. The non-integer values are much less likely, since the odds of the two middle points hitting the boundary is low. The integers values do tend to a Guassian.

```
middleMean[n_, range_] := Module[{res}, 
     res = Sort@Table[RandomChoice[Range[range]], {n}];
     Mean[{res[[n/2]], res[[n/2 + 1]]}]
  ]

Histogram[Table[middleMean[500, 50], {1000}], 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

According to "Median." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. 11 Jun. 2019. Web. 3 Jul. 2019, the median of a uniformly distributed variable is (b-a)/2.  In general, for the Uniform, Normal, and Exponential distributions, Mathematica reports the same medians as the Wikipedia article.  I did not try the other distributions for which the Wikipedia article gave medians.

Comment: This question is about the *distribution* of the median, not its expectation value.

Comment: I just changed the title to include the word “distribution”.